# How to connect two different PCs between two different networks using a java chat application?

Tags: java, networking, ip, chat

I have a chat application client server which run on a LAN without a server.

this is the server class:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connessione;
private BufferedReader dalClient;
private PrintStream alClient;
private String name;

public Server(String name) {
    this.name = name;

    try {
        InetAddress IP=InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("IP of my system is := "+IP.getHostAddress());
        server = new ServerSocket(1000, 5);
        System.out.println("Server attivo");
        connessione = server.accept();
        dalClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connessione.getInputStream()));
        alClient = new PrintStream(connessione.getOutputStream());
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
} // Server()

public void conversazione() {
    String messaggio = "";
    BufferedReader t = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {

        alClient.println("Sei connesso al server! Digita /logout per effetuare la disconnessione.\n");

        while(!messaggio.equals("/logout")) {
            messaggio = dalClient.readLine();
            System.out.println(messaggio);
            if(!messaggio.equals("/logout")) {
                messaggio = t.readLine();
                alClient.println(name+" scrive: "+ messaggio);
            }
        } // while
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Conversazione interrotta");
    }
} 
}
```

and this is the client class:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Client {
private Socket connessione;
private BufferedReader dalServer;
private PrintStream alServer;
private String name;

public Client(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    BufferedReader t = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {
        int porta = getLocalPort();
        System.out.println("Porta locale: " + porta);
        System.out.println("Inserire indirizzo IP server: ");
        String indirizzo = t.readLine();
        connessione = new Socket(indirizzo, 1000);
        dalServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connessione.getInputStream()));
        alServer = new PrintStream(connessione.getOutputStream());

    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

} // Client()

public void conversazione() {
    String messaggio = "";
    BufferedReader t = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        while(!messaggio.equals("/logout")) {
            messaggio = dalServer.readLine();
            System.out.println(messaggio);
            if(!messaggio.equals("/logout")) {
                messaggio = t.readLine();
                alServer.println(name+" scrive: "+messaggio);
            }
        } // while
        connessione.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Conversazione interrotta");
    }
} // conversazione()
}
```

and i have other two class files which i use to run the codes above that are the follow:

this is the class which i execute to run the server side:

```
public class ProvaServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server s = new Server(args[0]);
        s.conversazione();
    }
}
```

this is the class which i execute to run the client side:

```
public class ProvaClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client c = new Client(args[0]);
        c.conversazione();
    }
}
```

The code works well if i open two prompt (on the same pc connected in the same network) and do that:
 - in one prompt i run server class
 - in the other prompt i run the client class 
After running client class i insert my localhost and it work well.

The code works well also if i open a prompt on a pc and the other prompt on another pc (but connected in the same network)
 - in one prompt (1st pc) i run server class
 - in the other prompt (2nd pc) i run the client class 
After running client class i insert the IP address (IPV4) of the other machine and it work well.

After this explanation, i ask you, how can i modify the code to make the code working beetween two PCs connected TO DIFFERENT NETWORKS whithout using a phisical server?

Comment: It is pretty simple: both machines need to be able to "reach" the other one. Thus it really doesn't matter in what network they are - but there must be a route from A to B. That is all that matters.

Comment: yes i know, but i don't know how to implement it. can you explain me that with some code?

Comment: The point is: as long as the other IP is reachable things just work. If the other machine is not reachable, then the two systems can't communicate. It is that simple.